# Code only working in edit mode, not on live view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to implement a tab element on my site. I am using Elementor via Wordpress. In the edit mode everything works fine, but one the live page the selection of the different tabs doesnt work.

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-target]')
const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-content]')

tabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const target = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.tabTarget)
    tabContents.forEach(tabContent => {
      tabContent.classList.remove('active')
    })
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
      tab.classList.remove('active')
    })
    tab.classList.add('active')
    target.classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li data-tab-target="#einsteiger" class="tab"><h3>Einsteiger</h3><p id="preis">bis 2.999 €</p></li>
  <li data-tab-target="#mittelklasse" class="active tab"><h3>Mittelklasse </h3><p id="preis">von 3.000 bis 4.499 €</p></li>
  <li data-tab-target="#high-end" class="tab"><h3>High-End</h3><p id="preis">ab 4.500 €</p></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="einsteiger" data-tab-content >
    <h1>test1</h1>
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div id="mittelklasse" data-tab-content class="active">
    <h1>test2</h1>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="high-end" data-tab-content >
    <h1>test3</h1>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/hisato/pen/dyMGBBa does this make a difference ? not posting it as an answer because I'm not sure if it's relevant